# How to keep my friends (100%) private on Facebook

Tags: facebook, friends

I'm considering setting up a Facebook account but have some concerns about privacy. Specifically, I don't want Facebook to provide the name of Friend A (say) to Friend B if I haven't agreed to this myself.

I'm aware that I can hide my list of friends on Facebook. The question is whether such friends will turn up on other peoples' "People You May Know" list.

For example, if I am friends with two people, A and B, and have hidden my friend list to everyone but myself, will person B see person A on the "People You May Know" list, or vice versa?

Please respond only if you're 100% sure about this.

Comment: The only way: Unfriend them all and Delete your account... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I just tested it.

Everyone who just asks for your friendship will get the "People you may know" from your friends list, so you do not even need to answer the friend request. Then your friends pop-up as people you may know.